# How can i write callback for setBackgroundImage function in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have successfully done to set background image in fabric canvas 
My code

```
 canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageSource, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), { 
                     // Fixed  object misplacing issue.
                     top: obj.top, // object top
                     left: obj.left, // object left
                     width: obj.width * obj.scaleX,
                     height: obj.height * obj.scaleY,
                     name:'back-img',
                     //angle:angles,
                     srno:"", // removed serial number of background image. becouse serial number is undefined
                     });
```

Now i facing the problem to set angle to background image

```
canvas.backgroundImage.setAngle(angle)
```

above single line code is not working  because it got executed before finishing the canvas.setBackgroundImage. 
In my understanding  `canvas.setBackgroundImage()` is the synchronous function so i want to write the callback to `canvas.setBackgroundImage()`

Note:-i don't want to define the angle property inside the `canvas.setBackgroundImage`() because my image position  got misplaced.

any help or suggestion is appreciated 
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (don't need the ".bind" after renderAll in CB):

```
function setBackgroundImageCB(angle, canvas) {
   canvas.backgroundImage.setAngle(angle);
   canvas.renderAll(canvas);
}
```

Do need ".bind" here

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageSource, setBackgroundImageCB.bind(this, angle,canvas), { 
                 // Fixed  object misplacing issue.
                 top: obj.top, // object top
                 left: obj.left, // object left
                 width: obj.width * obj.scaleX,
                 height: obj.height * obj.scaleY,
                 name:'back-img',
                 //angle:angles,
                 srno:"", // removed serial number of background image. because serial number is undefined
                 });
```

Yes, the second parameter inside setBackgroundImage function is a callback, but without the ".bind", it was executing immediately.  It was not waiting for setBackgroundImage to execute it.

Comment: second param is callback it will execute before setting the background image , it's not worked

Comment: No Callbacks are usually executed after the outer function completes, in this case after setting the background image. Check in your developer console if you are getting any errors?

Comment: then why canvas.setbackgroundImage.setAngle(45) not worked , its because of still background image is not set to canvas , any way i fixed this issue different way , thaks for your helf

Comment: I am not sure, what could be issue here, but you can post your solution here, so everyone can know ;)